# Undefined control sequence when using tufte-latex package

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a pandoc grid table in an otherwise brand-new bookdown project:

```
# Hello bookdown 

All chapters start with a first-level heading followed by your chapter title, like the line above. There should be only one first-level heading (`#`) per .Rmd file.

+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Rendering to html and normal pdf via `bookdown::gitbook` and `bookdown::pdf_book` are fine, however rendering to a tufte format via `tufte::tufte_book` or `bookdown::tufte_book2` fails with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> @{} >{\raggedright \arraybackslash 
                                              }p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep...
l.93 ...umnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.29}}@{}}
```

The table structure is different to the other tables generated:

```
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.22}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.22}}
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 4\tabcolsep) * \real{0.29}}@{}}
\toprule
Fruit & Price & Advantages \\
...
```

Therefore I think the source of the problem is in the `tufte-latex` package which tufte_book relies on, but I am unable to narrow it down further.

The tex code of the document is [here](https://pastebin.com/BTgnRqEW) - the culprit section starts at line 96.

Comment: The .tex file you shared works fine for me with texlive 2021. Can you show your .log file?

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/tufte/issues/104.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue in the **tufte** package.

It has now been fixed in dev version 0.10.2 one can install from github

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tufte")
```

The fix will be on CRAN for next version 0.11

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vary similar error as OP but outside of tufte-latex, you might have run into changed pandoc table width calculation as described in [this related issue](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown/issues/122#issuecomment-771855855). The suggested solution is adding `arrray` and `calc` to your template, e.g.:

```latex
\usepackage{array,calc}
```